# Automatic Failover between Azure Internal Load Balancers

Tags: azure-traffic-manager, azure-load-balancer

We are moving a workflow of our business to Azure. I currently have two VMs as an HA pair behind an internal load balancer in the North Central US Region as my production environment. I have mirrored this architecture in the South Central US Region for disaster recovery purposes. A vendor recommended I place an Azure Traffic Manager in front of the ILBs for automatic failover, but it appears that I cannot spec ILBs as endpoints for ATM. (For clarity, all connections to these ILBs are through VPNs.)

Our current plan is to put the IPs for both ILBs in a custom-built appliance placed on-prem, and the failover would happen on that appliance. However, it would greatly simplify things if we could present a single IP to that appliance, and let the failover happen in Azure instead.

Is there an Azure product or service, or perhaps more appropriate architecture that would allow for a single IP to be presented to the customer, but allow for automatic failover across regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you could [configure an application gateway with an internal load balancer (ILB) endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-application-gateway-with-private-frontend-ip). In this case, you will have a private frontend IP configuration for an Application Gateway. The APPGW will be deployed in a dedicated subnet, it will exist on the same VNet with your internal backend VMs. Please note in this case you can directly add the private VMs as the backends instead of internal load balancer frontend IP address because of private APPGW itself is an internal load balancer.

Moreover, APPGW also could configure a public frontend IP configuration, if so, you can configure the APPGW public frontend IP as the endpoints of the Azure traffic manager.

Hope this could help you.